# Android Studio: 'Gradle project refresh failed' after updating

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2

I have searched a lot about this issue and nothing has worked to me. I have just updated Android Studio to 2.2 Preview 3 and I get the following error:

```
Gradle'myApp' project refresh failed

Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3813)
    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3800)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.doCreateTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:399)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:361)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:341)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:334)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.createTempFile(FileUtil.java:1479)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:964)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addLocalMavenRepoInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:957)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addLocalMavenRepoInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:923)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getExtraCommandLineArgs(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:339)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:174)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:72)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:757)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:741)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:72)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have checked my gradle settings, cleaned and rebuild my project and even deleted the .gradle files.

This is my build.gradle (module app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fogames.thecolourapp"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.3"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
}
```

EDIT: I have been able to build and install the APK once, but most of the time I get this error or 'unknown error'.

EDIT2: on Gradle Build I get:

```
Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: unknown.
```

On the Gradle Console I get:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:compileDebugSources]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File - Invalidate Cache and Restart`. You should be good after this unless you changed something in your `build.gradle` after updating. If you did, revert and check if that is what caused the issues.

Comment: After two year I step into same issue after updating from Android Studio 2.1 to 2.2. Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: AS 2.2 has a change in the project structure. The issue could be completely different. Suggest reimporting/converting.

Comment: I am facing same issues in Android studios 2.2.3. Did someone find a solution. Any help will be appreciated. I even tried re installing Android studios but this error remains.

Comment: Well I had to solve this issue by re installing Studios to a new location on Computer and thoroughly removing the older one(Even the SDK folder).